# If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous then $\phi:X\owns x\rightarrow f(x)\in f(X)$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let be $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{S})$ two topological spaces and let be $f$ a continuous function from $X$ into $Y$ and we consider the function $\phi$ from $X$ to $f(X)$ defined by the condition
$$
\phi(x):=f(x)
$$
so we claim that $\phi$ is continuous in the subspace $f(X)$. So to prove the assertion we remember that any open set $V$ of $f(X)$ is equal to the intersection between $f(X)$ and some open set $U$ of $Y$, that is $V\equiv f(X)\cap U$: since for any open set $V$ of $f(X)$ it result that $\phi^{-1}(V):=f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(f(X)\cap U)=f^{-1}(f(X))\cap f^{-1}(U)=X\cap f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U)$ and since by the continuity of $f$ we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, so it is clear that $\phi$ is continuous.

It is the proof correct? Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

The subspace topology on a subset $B \subset Y$ of a topological space $Y = (Y,\mathcal T)$ is defined as $\mathcal T_B  = \{U \cap B \mid U \in \mathcal T \}$. What is the deeper reason for this definition? Of course, it appears absolutely natural to define it like  that, but here is a characterization explaining it by an "extremal property":

$\mathcal T_B$ is the *coarsest topology* on $B$ making the inclusion  $i : B \to Y$ continuous.

In fact, if $i$ is continuous with respect to a topology $\mathcal T'$, then $\mathcal T_B = \{i^{-1}(U) \mid U \in \mathcal T\} \subset \mathcal T'$. Thus $\mathcal T_B$ is the coarsest topology with this continuity property.

Another characterization of $\mathcal T_B$ is this:

Let us say that a topology $\mathcal T'$ on $B$ is *admissible* if for all functions $f : X \to (B,\mathcal T')$ defined on a topological space $X$, one has the following equivalence:  $f$ is continuous if and only if $i \circ f : X \to Y$ is continuous.

Note that in this definition we do not assume that $i : (B,\mathcal T') \to Y$ is continuous. Also note that "admissible" is just an adhoc phrase which you will probably not find in the literature.

1. $\mathcal T_B$ is admissible: Trivially, if $f$ is continuous, then $i \circ f$ is continuous. Conversely, let $i \circ f$ be continuous. Then for each $V \in \mathcal T_B$ we have $V = U \cap B$ for some $U \in \mathcal T$ and thus $f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(U \cap B) = f^{-1}(i^{-1}(U)) = (i \circ f)^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.
2. $\mathcal T_B$ is the *only* admissible topology on $B$:
   Let $\mathcal T'$ be an admissible topology. Since $id_B : (B,\mathcal T') \to (B,\mathcal T')$ is continuous, also $i = i \circ id_B: (B,\mathcal T') \to Y$ is continuous and therefore $\mathcal T_B \subset \mathcal T'$. Moreover, $id'_B : (B,\mathcal T_B) \to (B,\mathcal T')$ has the property that $i = i \circ id'_B$ is continuous, thus $id'_B$ is continuous and we conclude $\mathcal T' \subset \mathcal T_B$.

This is frequently applied as follows:

Let $F : X \to Y$ be continuous and $F(X) \subset B \subset Y$. Then the "codomain restricton" $F' : X \to (B,\mathcal T_B)$ of $F$ is continuous.

This is true because $i \circ F' = F$.
In your question this occurs for $B = f(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt looks correct to me.

Note that the converse is also true, and you can also prove that the restriction in the domain remains continuous (because the inclusion map is continuous, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct.

Your claim can be rephrased in the following manner:

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if $f:X\rightarrow f(X)$ is continuous.

I will provide two proofs.

**Proof 1:** 
Forward Direction:

If $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous, then I claim that the function, 
$\phi: X\rightarrow f(X)$ given by $\phi(x)=f(x)$ is continuous. Take any open set $V\subseteq f(X)$. By definition of the subspace topology, $V=U\cap f(X)$ where $U$ is open set in $Y$.

Claim :
$\phi^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(V)$.

Note, this is intuitively clear, by definition of $\phi$. To spell it out more explicitly, observe:

$x\in \phi^{-1}(V)$ $\iff$ $\phi(x)\in V$ $\iff$ $f(x)\in V$ $\iff$ $x\in f^{-1}(V)$.

Further observe: $f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(U\cap f(X)) =f^{-1}(U)\cap f^{-1}(f(X))=f^{-1}(U)\cap X=f^{-1}(U)$. By continuity of $f$, since $U$ is open in $Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ and so $\phi^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

Hence we have proved the forward direction.

**Backwards direction:**
To prove the backwards direction, we assume $\phi: X\rightarrow f(X)$, given by $\phi(x)=f(x)$ is continuous. Now we must show that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Let $V$ be an open subset of $Y$. Consider $f^{-1}(V)$.

The problem in this case is that $\phi$ need not be surjective, and so $f(X)$ may fail to be the codomain of $f$, $Y$. In which case, I claim the following:

$\phi^{-1}(V\cap f(X))=f^{-1}(V)$:

Case 1: If $V\subseteq f(X)$ then we are done, as this simply reduces to what we did in the forward direction.

Case 2: $V$ is not a subset of $f(X)$. Observe,

$x \in \phi^{-1}(V\cap f(X))$ $\iff$ $\phi(x)\in V\cap f(X)$ $\iff$ $f(x)\in V\cap f(X)$ $\iff$ $x\in f^{-1}(V)$.

Since $V\cap f(X)$ is open in $f(X)$, it follows that $\phi^{-1}(V\cap f(X))$ is open in $X$, and thus, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. Therefore, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

**Proof 2:**
In this proof, I must first define the inclusion map.

**Definition:** Let $X$ be a set and $A\subseteq X$. The map defined by
$\iota_A: A\hookrightarrow X$, given by $\iota_A(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$ is called the **inclusion map.**

Note that when $A=X$, the inclusion map on $A$ is simply the identity map on $X$.

Now, with reasonably developed intuition, it would seem very plausible that the inclusion map, like the identity (on a space with the same topology in domain and codomain) is continuous. This is true. In fact, here is the proof:

**Proposition:** Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$.
Then $\iota_A$ is continuous.

Note we require $A$ to be equipped with the subspace topology, this is important.

***Proof:***

Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$. I must show that $\iota_A(U)$ is open in $X$.

Note that the inclusion map has domain $A$, and so we make the (reasonable) claim:

$\iota_A^{-1}(U)=U\cap A$.

To see this more explicitly, observe:

$x\in \iota_A^{-1}(U)$ $\iff$  $x \in A$ and $\iota_A(x)\in U$ $\iff$ $x\in A\cap U$.

Since $U\cap A$ is open in $A$, we are done.

Now, I will prove an important theorem related to subspace topology, called the characteristic property of subspaces.

**Theorem:** Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$ and $Y$ any topological space.

$f:Y\rightarrow A$ is continuous if and only if $\iota_A \circ f$ is continuous.

**Proof:**

Suppose $f: Y\rightarrow A$ is continuous. Since $\iota_A$ is continuous, and the composition of continuous maps is continuous, the forward direction immediately holds. Conversely, suppose $\iota_A \circ f$ is continuous. Let $V$ be open in $A$. I must show that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $Y$. Well, since we have $V=V\cap A$, we deduce that $\iota_A^{-1}(V)=V$. Thus,

$f^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(\iota_A^{-1}(V))$ is open by assumption.

This theorem is in particular important because now we can deduce the following:

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous then $f:X\rightarrow T$, where $T$ is a subspace of $Y$ containing $f(X)$ is continuous.

***Proof:***

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Let $T$ be a subspace of $Y$ containing $f(X)$.
We want to show that $f:X\rightarrow T$ is continuous.
By the characteristic property of subspaces, it suffices to show that

$\iota_T\circ f$ is continuous. Well, certainly that is the case, since the composition of continuous maps is continuous. Hence we are done.

Q.E.D.

***I urge someone to read over what I wrote, because I have written this fairly quickly, without paper.***